# If $A_k\to \infty$ and $B_k=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k A_i$ then is the limit of $\frac{A_k}{B_k}$ always zero?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Assume that the terms of the sequence $\{A_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ are positive and that
 $A_k\to \infty$. 
Is the following limit 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{A_k}{\sum_{i=1}^k A_i},
$$
always equal to zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit could be pretty much anything between $0$ and $1$:

**Example I.** $A_n=s^n$, $s>1$. Then
$$
\frac{A_n}{\sum_{k=1}^n A_k}=\frac{(s-1)s^n}{s^{n+1}-1}\to \frac{s-1}{s}.
$$

**Example II.** $A_n=n$, then
$$
\frac{A_n}{\sum_{k=1}^n A_k}=\frac{2n}{n(n+1)}\to 0.
$$

**Example III.** $A_n=n!$, then
$$
\frac{A_n}{\sum_{k=1}^n A_k}\to 1.
$$
Chalenge. Construct a sequence $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, for which we do not have convergence.

Answer (score 3):

No. If $A_k=a^k$ for every $k$, with $a\gt1$, then $A_k\to\infty$ and the limit of the ratio you consider is not zero. Actually every limit in $[0,1]$ is possible, as sequences of ratios without a limit, and even sequences of ratios dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Now I know why I could not prove it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A_i = 2^i$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^k A_i = 2 + 4 + \dots + 2^k = 2^{k+1}-2$, and so $\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{A_k}{\sum_{i=1}^k A_i} = \frac{1}{2}$